# Cannot ping Google on VirtualBox with NAT routing set up

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, nat

I am using VirtualBox right now with NAT.  I'm not able to ping www.google.com.  It says: "Name or service not known."

Alright, so the problem is with DNS maybe?

Here is my output for ifconfig:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe89:3db  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:89:03:db  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 3  bytes 1240 (1.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 22  bytes 2434 (2.3 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16  bytes 960 (960.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Ok, so I don't have an IP address for eth0.  Maybe that is the problem? But I still don't have one after I try dhclient -r.

Also, maybe I don't understand VirtualBox networking.  Why don't I have an interface for wifi?  My host machine is only using WiFi and not ethernet.

Comment: Why do you use `-r`? That option tells dhclient to release any address leases it currently has – literally the opposite of getting an IP address.

Comment: Derp - I thought it stood for "renew". I tried dhclient -1 and got an IP address.

Comment: You won't have wifi, as the implementation of the network is visualised. You will have `eth0` no-matter what the host has.

Comment: What is the guest OS? Have you told it to configure the network automatically (using DHCP)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Ok, so I don't have an IP address for eth0. Maybe that is the problem?

Yes, and you don't have DNS servers in resolv.conf either. You need to get both using DHCP.

> But I still don't have one after I try dhclient -r.

The `-r` option tells dhclient to *release* (give back) any address leases it currently has. It is the opposite of getting an IP address. Instead you want just `dhclient eth0` – obtaining a new lease is already the program's default mode of operation.

> Also, maybe I don't understand VirtualBox networking. Why don't I have an interface for wifi? My host machine is only using WiFi and not ethernet.

VirtualBox emulates an entire machine, including the motherboard, disks, GPUs, and of course network interfaces. (Mostly by necessity: you can't easily share a random PCI device between two machines; enterprise Ethernet adapters allow this using SR-IOV, but Wi-Fi adapters would additionally need a separate radio and a separate antenna for each machine using it...)

So what you're seeing is not your host machine's Ethernet – it's a virtual Ethernet card, often based on Intel e1000 series. How it is attached to a real network depends on your VirtualBox settings for each VM.

(In "NAT" mode, VirtualBox itself acts like a router and provides DHCP – the VM is in a virtual subnet. Don't be surprised if the IP addresses will be different from your real LAN.)